# C# - knowing time

Tags: c#, math, time, timer

This is my code:

```
IdleTime = System.Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
int hour = ((IdleTime + 500) / 86400000);
int min = ((IdleTime + 500) / 60000) - (hour * 60);
int sec = ((IdleTime + 500) / 1000) - (min * 60);
```

I got a idle timer for this in a timer that tracks the idle time

The seconds works and the min works but im not sure if it will work once the hour hits 24 I think it might bug out on me coz 86400000 millie milliseconds is a day and I have the sec and the min getting data from the previous time like sec is gettings data from the min. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

```
IdleTime = System.Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
int hours = IdleTime / 3600000;
int minutes = IdleTime / 60000 - hour * 60;
int seconds = IdleTime / 1000 - min * 60;
```

I'm not sure why you substract 500 from `IdleTime`.

Comment: me either, its code that I got off a website that turned it into a second, but I made this project over 2 years ago, so yeh, also your code seems to work

Comment: @user1892884: The reason 500 milliseconds is added to the idle time is to round the seconds part instead of truncating it. 0 - 0.5 seconds are considered 0 seconds while 0.5 - 1 second is considered 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you work with the `TimeSpan` type to avoid doing the math yourself:

```
int milliseconds = Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
TimeSpan idleTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds + 500);
int hour = (int) idleTime.TotalHours;
int minutes = idleTime.Minutes;
int seconds = idleTime.Seconds;
```